# Quartz Schedular in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, quartz-scheduler

I have OperationLog class and I create 1000 records with the information which supplied by  another class called Validator.

```
def list = {
        params.max = Math.min(params.max ? params.int('max') : 10, 100)
        [operationLogInstanceList: OperationLog.list(params), operationLogInstanceTotal: OperationLog.count()]
    }

    def create = {
        def operationLogInstance = new OperationLog()
        operationLogInstance.properties = params
        operationLogInstance.validator = Validator.get(params.validatorId)
        operationLogInstance.operation = Operation.get(params.operationId)
        return [operationLogInstance: operationLogInstance]
    }

    def save = {
        int i = 0;
    1000.times {
        def operationLogInstance = new OperationLog(params)
        operationLogInstance.validator = Validator.get((i));
        operationLogInstance.save(flush: true)                   
        i ++;
    }
    redirect(action: "list")
    }
}
```

My question is this. How can I create these records one by one with the help of quartz scheduler and each should be saved in 5 minutes.

**Note:** I created a job (MyJob.groovy) already. I have my execute and triggers method all empty.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you, you get data from the user? And you want to save this data 1000 times, every 5 minutes one?
So you want to call a service to do this (the data as a parameter)?

So this could be done via Threads (anywhere, should also work in controllers...

```
Thread.start {
    1000.times {
        def operationLogInstance = new OperationLog(params)
        println(params.validator)
        operationLogInstance.validator = Validator.get(params.validator.id);
        operationLogInstance.save(flush: true)                   
    }
    wait(300000)
}
```

May be there is a OperationLog.withSession { ... } necessary around it.

Alternatively you could feed a quatz job (using a service that save the logs you want to save...)looking like this:

```
class OperationLogJob {

static triggers = {
    simple name:'Operation Save', startDelay:0, repeatInterval:300000
}

def sessionRequired = true

def concurrent = false

def operationsLogService

def execute() {
    def operationLogInstance = operationsLogService.getLogsToSave()
    if(operationLogInstance) {
            operationLogInstance.validator = Validator.get(params.validator.id);
            operationLogInstance.save(flush: true)                   
        }
    }       
}

}
```

The *operationsLogService.getLogsToSave()* method returns (and deletes) a value from a stack that you can fill in the controller method (eg. 1000.times {operationsLogService.addLog(log) })

Comment: thank you for your answer. validator information comes from db and i just call every validator object

'operationLogInstance.validator = Validator.get((i))'

(please see the code fix in my question)